# Unit Testing/Mocking in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, dependency-injection, mocking

So let's say I have this bit of code:

```
import coolObject

def doSomething():
   x = coolObject()
   x.coolOperation()
```

Now it's a simple enough method, and as you can see we are using an external library(`coolObject`). 
In unit tests, I have to create a mock of this object that roughly replicates it. Let's call this mock object `coolMock`.

My question is how would I tell the code when to use `coolMock` or `coolObject`? I've looked it up online, and a few people have suggested dependency injection, but I'm not sure I understand it correctly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try to search: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+mock ?

Comment: See also https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def doSomething(cool_object=None):
  cool_object = cool_object or coolObject()
  ...
```

In you test:

```
def test_do_something(self):
   cool_mock = mock.create_autospec(coolObject, ...)
   cool_mock.coolOperation.side_effect = ...
   doSomthing(cool_object=cool_mock)
   ...
   self.assertEqual(cool_mock.coolOperation.call_count, ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

As Dan's answer says, one option is to use dependency injection: have the function accept an optional argument, if it's not passed in use the default class, so that a test can pass in a moc.

Another option is to use the `mock` library ([here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock) or [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html)) to replace your `coolObject`.

Let's say you have a `foo.py` that looks like

```
from somewhere.else import coolObject

def doSomething():
    x = coolObject()
    x.coolOperation()
```

In your `test_foo.py` you can do:

```
import mock

def test_thing():
    path = 'foo.coolObject'  # The fully-qualified path to the module, class, function, whatever you want to mock.
    with mock.patch('foo.coolObject') as m:
       doSomething()
       # Whatever you want to assert here.
       assert m.called
```

The `path` you use can include properties on objects, e.g. `module1.module2.MyClass.my_class_method`. A big gotcha is that you need to mock the object *in the module being tested*, not where it is defined. In the example above, that means using a path of `foo.coolObject` and not `somwhere.else.coolObject`.